# Why we haven't put 9 patched images in mipmap folder?

Tags: android

What is the difference of android studio's `mipmap-hdpi` folder and previous eclipse used `drawable-hdpi`? here my question is why we haven't put 9 patched images in mipmap folder? suppose an image name is 'calender_icon' then 9 patched images full qualifier name is 'calander_icon.9.png', if we put it on mipmap folder then raise some errors regarding the naming, how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

`mipmap` is for Launcher icons. place your launcher icon in that folder and use it using `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. it is not android studio specific.

Answer (score 1):

In mipmap folders you should place the icons that you will use in your app (es. launcher icon), in drawable folders all others images.

You should find both folders both in Android Studio than and Eclipse.